# Goal is to find common prefix between two c strings (must use specific function header)

Tags: c++

I encounter problems when i call the function in my main function
Function definition is const char and I am using strings which i can't pass
The last definition of the function "char prefix[]" no clue what to do with it

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void prefix(const char s1[], const char s2[], char prefix[]);  //Don't know what's the use of char prefix[]

    int main()
    {
        string s1;
        string s2;


        cout << "Enter two sentences to store in two different strings" << endl;
        getline(cin, s1);
        getline(cin, s2);
        const char *char1 = &s1[0];
        const char *char2 = &s2[0];

        prefix(char1, char2, );
        return 0;
    }

    void prefix(const char a[], const char b[], char prefix[]) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (; a[i] != 0 /* not a null char */ && a[i] == b[i] /* chars are 
 equal */; ++i)
            prefix[i] = a[i]; // copy char to prefix
        prefix[i] = 0; // null terminate prefix
    }
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate memory for the prefix and pass a pointer to this memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::getline;
using std::string;

void prefix(const char s1[], const char s2[], char prefix[]);

int main()
{
    string s1;
    string s2;

    cout << "Enter two sentences to store in two different strings\n";
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);
    const char *char1 = &s1[0];
    const char *char2 = &s2[0];
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> p = std::make_unique<char[]>(std::min(s1.length(), s2.length()));

    prefix(char1, char2, p.get());
    cout << p.get();
    return 0;
}

void prefix(const char a[], const char b[], char prefix[]) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; a[i] != 0 && a[i] == b[i]; ++i)
        prefix[i] = a[i];
}
```